# idirs-vim <leader>c sometimes deletes the line

Tags: vim, idris

I'm beginning with idris and idris-vim. But sometimes `\c (IdrisCaseSplit)` deletes the line I'm on. I try with the following program:

```
vApp : Vect n (a -> b) -> Vect n a -> Vect n b
```

then I put the cursor over `vApp` and press `\d` and I get:

```
vApp : Vect n (a -> b) -> Vect n a -> Vect n b
vApp xs ys = ?vApp_rhs
```

I go to `xs` in the first case and press `\c` and I get:

```
vApp : Vect n (a -> b) -> Vect n a -> Vect n b
vApp [] ys = ?vApp_rhs_1
vApp (x :: xs) ys = ?vApp_rhs_2
```

So far, so good, but if I go to `ys` in the first case (`vApp [] ys`) and press `\c`, the whole line is deleted.

**Why is the line deleted? How can I get the desired behavior (replace ys for [])?**

The same thing happens if I try to case split ys in the second case, `vApp (x :: xs) ys`.

- I'm using idris 0.9.14.3 on Mac OSX, VIM 7.4.
- idris-vim activated with with pathogen.
- idris-vim is working (\t works fine, for example).
- :map returns that `\c` is in fact mapped to `:call IdrisCaseSplit()<CR>`
- I've tried wiht a minimal vimrc, to avoid any interference.

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE:** [It seems a bug in idris itself?](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/1134)